# Warp/Distort image in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, cgcontext, distortion

I have a CGContext/objective-c question....

I have a path defined by 4 corner-points. Which I got via a camera processing. 
So it is a perspectively transformed rect, but it is not given how.

What I want to do is to fit an image within that rect. 
I don't want to scale it and use a mask, i want to set the image's corner-points to the given path and display the distorted image perfectly fit and transformed.

I am not looking for a fisheye, bulp or simmilar I just want to reposition it's cornerpoints.

Hope it is clear what I have ment. Thanks in advance

Add-on: As far as I know, CGAffineTransform can only Scale, Translate and Rotate... 2D AND 3D What I want is something like the "Distort"-Transformation of Photoshop: youtube.com/watch?v=mHPCKoRNOx8 where you can drag one point!

Comment: I suspect you want something akin to CGAffineTransform, but that's not really my bailiwick, so I can't suggest anything specific.

Comment: As far as I know, CGAffineTransform can only Scale, Translate and Rotate... 2D AND 3D
What I want is something like the "Distort"-Transformation of Photoshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHPCKoRNOx8 where you can drag one point!